# opengl text font size

Tags: text, fonts, size, glut

I'm trying to show some text overlay but I need it to be bigger than size 24. the problem is I can't find a way to do that!
At the moment I'm using:

GLvoid *font_style = GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24;

How can I increase the size of it? (it's no problem if I need to change to something else other than times roman)

Answer (score 0):

Try render the text with [FTGL](http://homepages.paradise.net.nz/henryj/code/) instead. You will get higher quality text and more flexibility.

(For normal font sizes, use the FTGL texture fonts. For large font sizes, use the FTGL vector fonts. For size 24 you should probably use the texture fonts.)